# Simple proof by contradiction in graph theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The question is as follows:
Let P be the longest path in a simple graph G, and let $\lambda$ be the length of P. Show that both the starting point and ending point of P must have degree $\le\lambda$.

My proof: Let s be be the starting vertex of P. Assume deg(s) > $\lambda$. If s is connected to every other vertex in P, then deg(s) = $\lambda$ $thus far$. Since deg(s) > $\lambda$, it follows that s is connected to some vertices not in P. This implies s is not the starting vertex, which is a contradiction. If s is $not$ connected to every other vertex in P, then the deg(s) $<\lambda$ $thus far$. Again, this means s must be connected to some vertices outside P, which is a contradiction. Therefore deg(s) $\le\lambda$. The same argument holds for the end vertex of P.

My proof does not involve the fact that P is the longest path in G, which leads me to doubt its validity. I would like a verification of my proof.

EDIT: If my proof is valid, does that mean that the above result is true regardless of whether P is the longest path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof does use the assumption that $P$ is the longest path.

```
This implies s is not the starting vertex, which is a contradiction.
```

By this, what you mean is that $P$ can be extended, which contradicts the assumption that $P$ is the longest path.

By saying, "if not, s wouldn't be the starting vertex", you mean $P$ can be extended. If $P$ were the the longest path, then such an extension wouldn't have been possible. Suppose you drop the assumption '$P$ is the longest path'. Then what happens? For instance, take the graph $K_3$ and a $1-$length path $P$, which is an edge, say $e=\big \{ s,t \big \}$. Here, $deg(s) = 2$, but $\lambda =1$.

Comment: Even if P is not the longest path, my proof still seems to work. The essence of my proof is, if P is $any$ path with a length $\lambda$, then deg(s) $\le$ $\lambda$ $necessarily$, if not s wouldn't be the starting vertex.

Comment: By saying, "if not, s wouldn't be the starting vertex", you mean P can be extended. If P were the the longest path, then such an extension wouldn't have been possible. Suppose you drop the assumption 'P is the longest path'. Then what happens? For instance, take the graph K_3. and a 1-length path P, which is an edge, say {x,y}. Here, deg(x) = 2, but lambda =1.

Answer (score 0):

For a path $P$ of length $\lambda$, you are trying to prove:

> If $P$ is a longest path in $G$, then the first and last vertices of $P$ have degree at most $\lambda$.

Your (correct) strategy here is to actually demonstrate the contrapositive statement:

> If either the first or last vertex of $P$ has degree larger than $\lambda$, then $P$ is not a longest path in $G$.

But you are right that your proof is demonstrating something a bit more than required. The only property of $P$ being a longest path that you are using is that $P$ is not contained in any longer path. This property can be true for other paths, even if they are not of maximum length. So actually your proof is also a proof for the following.

> If $P$ is a *maximal* path (i.e., $P$ is not contained in a longer path), then the first and last vertices of $P$ have degree at most $\lambda$.